# tkinter callback event to retrieve value from Entry and write to text file

Tags: python, function, user-interface, tkinter, event-handling

*First of all, i am trying to create a register system saved into textfile(not real system, i know its not safe to write into textfiles) Created the GUI and then i defined multiple functions which is Menu, register and submit. Submit function is nested and inside register function. The problem is when i nested the functions it doesn't write into textfiles, but when i delete the register function, it works.
When i press register and write something in the Entry box, it didnt record to the text files, i have been scratching my head as to find what the error in my code is.

Edit: I now have put a picture to get better understanding. the blue window is main menu and its the mainloop and the yellow window is appearing when i click register button.*

[picture of what should be my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTqLH.jpg)

```
from tkinter import *

def Register():

    def Submit():


        elev = open("bruker.txt","a", encoding="utf-8")

        elev.write(brukeridinc.get()+"\n")

        elev.write(fornavn.get()+"\n")

        elev.write(etternavn.get()+"\n")

        



register = Tk()

register.geometry("500x500")

register.configure(bg="yellow")

register.title("Bibliotekapp Login")



label_brukerid = Label(register, text="Brukerid:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))

label_brukerid.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)



label_fornavn = Label(register, text="Fornavn:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))

label_fornavn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)



label_etternavn = Label(register, text="Etternavn:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))

label_etternavn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)



brukeridinc= StringVar()

entry_brukerid= Entry(register, width=10, textvariable=brukeridinc, font=("Arial", 25))

entry_brukerid.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 



fornavn= StringVar()

entry_fornavn= Entry(register, width=10, textvariable=fornavn, font=("Arial", 25))

entry_fornavn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 



etternavn= StringVar()

entry_etternavn= Entry(register, width=10, textvariable=etternavn, font=("Arial", 25))

entry_etternavn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 



button_resultat= Button(register, text="Enter", command=Submit, height=2, width=15)

button_resultat.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)



informasjon= StringVar()

entry_informasjon= Entry(register, width=24, textvariable=informasjon, state="readonly", font=("Arial", 25))

entry_informasjon.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)


#GUI

start = Tk()

start.geometry("500x500")

start.configure(bg="lightblue")

start.title("Bibliotekapp")



button_register = Button(start, text="Register", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25), command=Register)

button_register.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)










start.mainloop()
```

Comment: I cannot run your code. First of all you start two Tk instances which is never should be done. Secondly, your usage of functions meaningless. You should make a reproducible minimal example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `start` is a local variable inside `menu()`, so how can you call `start.mainloop()` outside the function?

Comment: Writing the three input values into the file without any separator between them is not good.  How do you extract the three values from a string without separators?

Comment: @acw1668 yes sorry it should say menu. and 3 input values is just for testing, i would have newline gradually, but this testing just to show that the code doesnt work

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ Please do elaborate more, I just want 3 functions inside menu. Menu: 1.Register 2.Login 3.Lån

Comment: @acw1668 Sorry now i edited the code, and the GUI should work now

Comment: Your code saves into the text file while i'm trying. What's the problem?

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ Not for me honestly, i tried IDLE and visualstudio both doesnt work :( . This is why i have been scratching my head for 2 days now

Comment: Okay now, problem is as I said, you have two Tk instances. Change register = Tk() into register = Toplevel() then your problem should be fixed. Also in your code snippet there are some problems with indentations. However I assume that it occurred while copy-paste your code and your original code indentations are ok

Comment: @MustafaKÜÇÜKDEMİRCİ OMG you are correct, now it works 100% Thanks . If i had reputation i would give upvote.

Comment: Your welcome. Happy to hear it worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not understand how you write code. You are using too many duplicates. I will not going to explain to you. In line 51 and 54 , I changed `command` to `None`. You can replace it.

Here is code:

```
from tkinter import *

start = Tk()
start.geometry("800x500")
start.configure(bg="lightblue")
start.title("Bibliotekapp")
 
def menu():
    start.geometry("500x500")
    start.title("Bibliotekapp")
    start.configure(bg="red")

def Register():
    start.geometry("800x800")
    start.configure(bg="yellow")
    start.title("Bibliotekapp Login")
     
def Submit():
    elev = open("bruker.txt", "r")
    sjekk = elev.read()

    if brukeridinc.get() in sjekk:
        informasjon.set("User already exists")

    else:
        elev.close()
        elev = open("bruker.txt", "a")
        elev.write(brukeridinc.get() + "")
        elev.write(fornavn.get() + "")
        elev.write(etternavn.get() + "\n")
        elev.close()
        informasjon.set("You are started")


#######    GUI  ############
label_brukerid = Label(start, text="Brukerid:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))
label_brukerid.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

label_fornavn = Label(start, text="Fornavn:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))
label_fornavn.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

label_etternavn = Label(start, text="Etternavn:", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25))
label_etternavn.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

brukeridinc= StringVar()
entry_brukerid= Entry(start, width=10, textvariable=brukeridinc, font=("Arial", 25))
entry_brukerid.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 

fornavn= StringVar()
entry_fornavn= Entry(start, width=10, textvariable=fornavn, font=("Arial", 25))
entry_fornavn.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 

etternavn= StringVar()
entry_etternavn= Entry(start, width=10, textvariable=etternavn, font=("Arial", 25))
entry_etternavn.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W) 

button_start = Button(start, text="start", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25), command=Submit)
button_start.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

button_login = Button(start, text="Login", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25), command=menu)
button_login.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)

button_lån = Button(start, text="Lån", bg="white", font=("Arial", 25), command=Register)
button_lån.grid(row=7, column=5, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=E)
 
informasjon= StringVar()
entry_informasjon= Entry(start, width=24, textvariable=informasjon, state="readonly", font=("Arial", 25))
entry_informasjon.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)
 
start.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Result Red:

[image]

Result for yellow:

[image]

Comment: Btw, I left out two functions. So you can add functions  for 2 buttons.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. However i want register inside menu function. So in menu, after i click Register it will open new window.So menu should have 3 function: start, login and lån. With your method, everything is in 1 place.

Comment: So u will to right your own function such as register, start and  lån. Same as u did with Submit() function. Actually, I don't know about register and  lån too.

Comment: Yes, but your method deleted def menu, def register. Def register should be inside def menu. It's nested function

Comment: Yes. you have to tell me what widgets you want to add.

Comment: I am sorry i put a picture in my question, the blue background is menu. When i click register, the yellow one shall appear

Comment: Now I understood.  Comment out for both menu and register function......register = Tk() . I just texted it. Don't forget add command in button.

Comment: I edited the code, now the GUI should work,  but the function still didnt work. You would see the GUI and everything but it never write to the textfiles

Comment: I tested my own file and it worked.

Comment: Sorry you still misunderstood me, I dont want 3 windows with 3 different colors. Please just run my code up there and you would understand what i meant. I have 1 mainloop single window which is Menu(blue). Inside menu there is 1 button : register button. When i clik this button a new window will appear which ask for ID, Surname and Last name.

Comment: U cannot use entry_informasjon= Entry. Better use tk.Text or tk.ScrolledText. Btw, it is not 3 windows.

Comment: Ok, so the problem is Entry value cannot write into textfiles? because when i change to Text, it works. But when i used Entry it doesnt work...

Comment: As fact I understood. U want to write to file? What is textfiles look like?

Comment: Somehow other user said my code works and it saved into textfiles.... i am so confused lol. the textfiles is simple : 1st column is number(1234) 2nd column is surname(David) 3rd column is last name(Copperfield).

Comment: Press start button to write  text file. It should be working  now. U should change  text "start" to "save?